# what is method to undersamplig multiclasses by python

Tags: python

I use python to achieve my project put I did not find code to under sampling multiclass because I will use classification in machine learning but target are 8 class in different size so how can do balance by under sampling not over sampling because my data is huge

Comment: I'm sure you'll get much better answers if you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, provide  a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and work on your spelling, grammar and interpunction

Answer (score 1):

Below are two different methods to do oversampling and undersampling.

**Over-sampling:**

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
sm = SMOTE(kind='svm',random_state=42)
X_resampled, Y_resampled = sm.fit_sample(X, Y)

from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler
ros = RandomOverSampler(random_state=0)
ros.fit(X, y)
X_resampled, y_resampled = ros.sample(X, y)
```

**Under-sampling:**

```
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler
rus = RandomUnderSampler(random_state=0)
rus.fit(X, y)
X_resampled, y_resampled = rus.sample(X, y)
```

**Link to explore more on imblearn package:**

https://imbalanced-learn.org/en/stable/generated/imblearn.under_sampling.RandomUnderSampler.html

Thanks,
Rajeswari Ponnuru.